# How to conduct C unit testing with googletest if using the _Generic macro

Tags: c, macros, googletest

I am trying to use Googletest to execute unit tests on a C macro that uses the `_Generic` macro.  The purpose of using the `_Generic` macro exists in this case to ensure that the user is passing a `typedef struct` that can only be one of several different `typedefs` as a form of run time type checking on the macro.  A simple snippet is shown below.

```
// This is written in the vector.h file
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_TYPE_VALID(T) _Generic( (T), SVector: true, \
                                        IVector: true, \
                                        default: false)

#define INIT_VECTOR(vec, length) do {
    bool dat_type = IS_TYPE_VALID(vec);
} while (0)



typedef struct 
{ 
    short *array;
    size_t allocated_length;
    size_t active_length;
} SVector;

typedef struct
{
    int *array;
    size_t allocated_length;
    size_t active_length;
} IVector;
```

The Googletest test case looks like the example below.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
extern "C" {
    #include "vector.h"
}
TEST (test_short_int, test_push_vector) {
    SVector vec;
    size_t length = 5;
    INIT_VECTOR(vec, length);
}
```

When I try to compile the simple code I get the following error.
`error: expected primary-expression before ':' token #define IS_TYPE_VALID(T) _Generic( (T), SVector: true, \`
This error implies that Googletest does not recognize the `_Generic` macro as legitimate code.  This may be an issue of trying to test C code with a C++ framework, but before I retool the unit tests to a C framework like CMocka, I would like to see if there is a way to fix this with Googletest.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `_Generic` doesn't exist in C++, so I don't think it should come as a surprise that trying to use it in a C++ program doesn't work.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I figured that was the case, but Googletest advertises the ability to test C code as a feature, so I was under the impression, although maybe falsely that it would recognize C syntax and features.

Comment: You might consider adding a C++ replacement for that macro with some overloaded functions.  Wrap it in an `#ifdef __cplusplus` that determines if the code is being compiled C++ or C.

Comment: By the way, `_Generic` is not a macro. It is an operator. If it were a macro (of some special kind), the unselected cases would be largely irrelevant, as they would not be in the replacement tokens. As an operator, all the cases are subject to the usual C rules for expressions. They may be unevaluated, but they are parsed.

Comment: What do you think about to divide the test into two translation units? Compile one as C, which accepts `_Generic`, and the other as the C++ test driver.